# Create prediction interval in ggplot (different data for points and ribbon geoms)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a prediction interval plot using ggplot2(). I hope to only plot points in the original data frame that are *outside* the prediction interval, and to plot the prediction interval ribbon for a sequence of x values created in another data frame that covers the minimum and maximum x values used in the original data frame. Below is a mwe to demonstrate the details:

```
library(ggplot2) 

dat <- data.frame(qsec=mtcars$qsec, wt=mtcars$wt)
m <- lm(wt ~ qsec, data = dat) 
mpi <- cbind(dat, predict(m, interval = "prediction"))
# Keep only points that are outside the prediction interval
plotPoints <- mpi[which(!(mpi$wt > mpi$lwr & mpi$wt < mpi$upr)),]

# Create prediction interval data frame with upper and lower lines corresponding to sequence covering minimum and maximum of x values in original dataset
newx <- seq(min(mpi$qsec), max(mpi$qsec), by=0.05)
pred_interval <- predict(m, newdata=data.frame(qsec=newx), interval="prediction", level = 0.95)
pred_interval <- as.data.frame(pred_interval)

# Below are three different attempts to plot the prediction upper and lower lines as ribbons and the points outside the prediction interval as points. Each attempt gives an error which is also commented.

# Error: Object 'qsec' not found
ggplot(data=plotPoints, aes(x = qsec, y = wt)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_ribbon(data=pred_interval, aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) 

# Error: Object 'wt' not found
ggplot(data=plotPoints, aes(x = qsec)) + geom_point(y = wt) + 
  geom_ribbon(data=pred_interval, aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) 

# Error: geom_ribbon requires the following missing aesthetics: x
ggplot(data=plotPoints) + geom_point(aes(x = qsec, y=wt)) + 
  geom_ribbon(data=pred_interval, aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)
```

Any advice on how to achieve this type of plot would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good work at troubleshooting. The answer is in the last error:

```
Error: geom_ribbon requires the following missing aesthetics: x
```

`geom_ribbon` needs some variable for the x-axis. You specify `qsec` in the main `ggplot` call, but this column is not in the `pred_interval` dataframe, so `geom_ribbon` gets lost. Try:

```
pred_interval$qsec = newx
ggplot(data=plotPoints, aes(x = qsec)) + geom_point(aes(y = wt)) + 
  geom_ribbon(data=pred_interval, aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your idea here. I am still getting an error when I run your solution "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'wt' not found".

Comment: Okay, I believe this needs to be done: ggplot(data=plotPoints, aes(x = qsec)) + geom_point(aes(y=wt)) + 
  geom_ribbon(data=pred_interval, aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)

Comment: @GreenStone oh yeah, it seems `geom_ribbon` still looks for the `y` aesthetic if it's included in the main plot. I will edit the answer, and considering accepting it, if it works.